I have $k$ sets $b_1..b_k$, $b_i \subseteq \{1,..,n\}$.
I have $k$ sets $b_1..b_k$, $b_i \subseteq \{1,..,n\}$.
$|b_i \cap b_j|$ is even.
$|b_i|$ is odd.
Is it true, that $k\leq n$?
It's easy to construct an example with $k=n$. $b_i = \{i\}$. But I struggle with finding one where $k>n$.

Yes, $k \leq n$.
Define the $k \times n$ incidence matrix $B$, where $b_{ij}=1$ if $j \in B_i, 0$ otherwise.  Now consider $A=B B^T$.  Then $a_{ij}= \vert b_i \cap b_j \vert$.
By assumption, every diagonal element of $A$ is odd and every off-diagonal element is even, so we know that $A \equiv I \pmod 2$.  Thus, $A$ is a non-singular $k \times k$ matrix and $\operatorname{rank}(A)=k$.  But because $A=B B^T$ and $\operatorname{rank}(B) \leq n$, we also have $\operatorname{rank}(A) \leq n$.  Thus $k \leq n$.
Take a look also at this similar question.

Why is every diagonal element of $A$ odd and every off diagonal element even?

Because each element $a_{ij}$ gives the size of $b_i \cap b_j$.
